# font-size is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am designing a layout of a website. But I notice that font-size is not working properly. I write a word "JETRO" inside a div. The height of div is 80px and font-size is 40px. I used "line-height:80px" to align the word middle from top to bottom. But its not working properly. It takes 25px from the top and 20px from the bottom and font size is showing 35px actually. What is wrong here?

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PSD to HTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-blog.css" media="all" />
    </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="leftRuler">

        </div>
        <div id="headerContent">
            <div id="logo">
                JETRO
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                MENU
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightRuler">

        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS Code is:

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: bebas; 
}

header{
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background: #b9b9b9;
background-color:#ffff99;
}

#leftRuler{
width: 15%;
height: 80px;
float: left;
}

#headerContent{
width: 70%;
height: 80px;
float: left;
background: #99FFFF; 
line-height: 80px; 
}

#rightRuler{
width: 15%;
right: 80px; 
float: left;
}

#logo{
height: 80px; 
float: left;
font-size: 40px; 
display: block; 
}

#menu{
float: right; 
}
```

Comment: It is a customized font named "bebas". all letters under this font is capitalized by default.

Comment: I tried with standard font and that works .. which likely mean that your custom font has other space values that pushes it more down .. setting font to 40px doesn't mean the letter "J" is 40px

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "font-size is showing 35px actually"?

Comment: Here is a link which describes fonts and there parts and will give you some understanding of how they get displayed ... http://designmodo.com/typography-basics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font size is not the height of the characters in pixels.

The font size in pixels isn't used directly, it's translated to font size in points, and that is used for the actual text rendering.

The font size in points doesn't even correspond to an exact measurement of the font, but to a size that makes the font look similar in size to other fonts when used with the same point size. With the font `Bebas` the font author obviously has decided that the font should be shown somewhat smaller than regular fonts, probably to compensate for the look of the font.

---

So, you can't expect the text to be the exact pixel size that you specify. Also different browsers do translation and rounding a bit different, so you can't even expect the result to be exactly the same between browsers.

Even factors like system font rendering settings and which screen is connected to the computer may affect the result, so you can't even expect the result to stay exactly the same even in the same browser on the same computer.

Basically trying to control text rendering exactly in browsers is a futile endeavour. You just have to try to understand the intensions of the font authors, and always consider that there are some variations in the text rendering.

---

You can adjust the size and positioning according to the font that you use, but you should still keep in mind what will happen if the visitor doesn't have access to the font (or if it fails to load) so that the text is shown in a different font.